# Azure VM, able to RDP even when not assigned to a NSG - ARM Model

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I have added a new VM to a Subnet that has no NSG assigned to. I have a NSG where I have added rules to allow 3389 (RDP) port, but I did not associate this NSG to either the Subnet or the VM n/w interface. But still I am able to RDP into it and am also being able to reach the web server. Basically n/w traffic to port 80 and 3389 is going through.

How come this can happen, when there is no NSG assigned. Does n/w interface of the VM allow this traffic by default? If so where can I find the allowed rules and how can I restrich such a traffic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with no NSG around nothing is being blocked (imagine NSG is a firewall, what happens when there is NO firewall?).

Attach the NSG and it will work as you expect it.

Comment: Ahh, I thought by default all the traffic would be denied. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: One interesting observation though, when I associate the NSG to Subnet and removed the Port 80 inbound, it still was allowing me to access the site. It only prevented when I associated the NSG to the n/w interface.
So whats the point of having NSGs at the subnet level. My understanding was that rules at subnet level will trickle down to the VM level.

Comment: yes they will. I'm not sure what your problema was. It might not drop established connections.

Comment: I doubt it as I restarted the VM, will run some more tests. Any ways , thanks for your help.

Comment: i'm 100% sure thats the case, NSG work fine. they are not broken.

Comment: Please double check the vm/nic is in the same subnet as nsg.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a basic SKU public IP address, everything is open by default. So, you need to use NSG to restrict traffic.
If you use a standard SKU public IP address, everything is closed by default. So, you should use NSG to open traffic.

By the description, you must be using a basic SKU public IP address.

Refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-addresses#sku